# Accessing a variable from anywhere in an Application(Android)

Tags: android, object

Is it possible to create a variable in the starting activity (eg : Book class in Activity 1)
and have it available anywhere in the application (eg Book class in Activity 3 , 4 &5) without actually passing it.

I am asking because my xml handler creates a series of objects be it also updates the xml file after any change is made to the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a static variable. As long as it's declared with appropriate access (e.g., `public`) it will be directly available to any activity in the same process. (This will be the default; you need to do extra work to get an activity into a separate process.)

It's common to separate out such global variables into a separate class.

However, be aware that if your app is pushed into the background, there's a chance that the process will be killed off and re-created. In that case, any data stored in static variables will be lost. Alternatives include using SharedPreferences, a data base, or a ContentProvider.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there is no easy way to have a class be available between all activities?

Comment: @Raigex - I think I said the opposite: just declare a class to hold your shared variables. You can make it a singleton class or else make all the shared variables static. If you need to protect the data against the process being killed off (as opposed to re-creating it on application re-launch), you need to be a little more careful.

Comment: I see thank you. Do you know any tutorials that do that. I mean the part where the data is protected from destruction

Comment: Never mind the above post. But just in case anyone stumbles upon this thread I have found a good place that explains about global class instance deletions. It is
http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: @Raigex - Take a look at [Saving Data Safely](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html). Also, the general topic of [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is essential reading.

Comment: @Raigex - Regarding extending the Application class (as that blog post recommends): there's not a lot of benefit to doing that over using global static variables. See, for instance, [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/uOQtQCtjGds) on Google Groups, particularly Dianne Hackborn's post.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a class, for example with the name GlobalVariables, which extends Application.

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Application
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml do this in the application tag:

```
<application android:label="@string/YourAppName" android:icon="@drawable/YourIcon"
                 android:name=".activities.GlobalVariables.">
```

Don´t forget the package path for declaring your class (similar you do for adding activities to manifest file).

Then you can access this class and its variables or methods from everywhere of your application. Do this in the onCreate method of any Activity:

```
GlobalVariables globalVariables = (GlobalVariables) getApplicationContext();
```

The Class extended from Application (e.g. our GlobalVariables here) will be created with the start of your app and will be available until the app will be destroyed.

You can have a HashMap or something, else where you can store your desired variable, in the GlobalVariables class. Push the variable from your first Activity into the GlovalVariables and pull it from the second trough getting an instance to the GlobalVariables. Like this (once again):

```
GlobalVariables globalVariables = (GlobalVariables) getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: The problem is that when the application is in the background, the `Application` object (and the entire process) can be destroyed by the operating system. Extending `Application` provides no more protection against this as compared to a simple singleton or static class.